# Bootstrap 4.0 dropdown menu not using the full height of the nav bar

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, menu, navbar, dropdown

Im looking for some help, im a bit new to programming and I have tried to google my way to a solution, but can´t figure it out. 
how can i get the dropmenu to use the full height of the nav bar?
I have tried to do it with CSS but can´t get it the work. I have added a picture 
showing the problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBgZZ.jpg)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Heima</title>


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/landing/styles.css">

    .navbar-dark:hover .navbar-nav:hover .nav-link:hover
{
color: #fff;
width: 100%;
}

.bg-color{
background-color: #18191a;
}

.dropdown:hover{
background-color: #2f2f30;
height: 10%;
}

a:hover{
link-color: #fff;
color: #fff;
}

a{
link-color: #fff;
color: grey;
}

.nav-item dropdown
{
width: 100%;
}

</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-color navbar-dark">
    <!-- Brand -->
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>

      <!-- Dropdown -->
     <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Akfør
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Dropdown link
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Dropdown link
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your `<li>`'s should be placed inside a `<ul>` element and you probably need to remove the vertical default padding of the `.navbar` by adding class `.py-0` to it

Comment: I did just try that, and it removed almost all of the spacing, but there is still a bit for space between the dropdown menu and the bottom/top of the navbar

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand your issue is the padding of the navbar.

Try adding the following to your css:

```
.navbar {
padding: 0px 1rem;
}
```

Or add the following class to your navbar:

```
py-0
```

This will remove the padding and therefore the dropdown shadow will use the full height of the navbar.